# Pandas groupby and update column values based on value of latest row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with columns(s) whose values have to be updated based on another row. I have an example below.

[image: Sample dataframe]

I want to update the value of the 'serial' column based on values from the last row (because it has the latest 'valid_from' date).

I want to use the groupby solution as there can be many ids.

The final data frame should look like this:
[image: solution_dataframe]

Any help is appreciated. Data frame code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['X', 'L1', 'S2', '2023-06-26', '2023-06-27'], ['X', 'L2', 'S2', '2023-06-27', '9999-01-01'], ['X', 'L2', 'S2', '2023-06-28', np.nan]], columns=['id', 'location', 'serial', 'valid_from', 'valid_to'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use an intermediate DataFrame, this is how to do what you want. You can calculate the last serial separately and then join the results to the original df.

```
replace_cols = ["location", "serial"]

last_values = df \
    .sort_values(["id", "valid_from"]) \
    [["id"] + replace_cols] \
    .groupby("id", as_index=False) \
    .agg(lambda x: list(x)[-1])

df = df \
    .merge(last_values, how="left", on="id", suffixes=["", "_last"]) \
    .drop(replace_cols, axis=1) \
    .rename({col + "_last": col for col in replace_cols}, axis=1)

df
```

Output:

```
    id  valid_from  valid_to    location    serial
0   X   2023-06-26  2023-06-27  L2          S3
1   X   2023-06-27  9999-01-01  L2          S3
2   X   2023-06-28  NaN         L2          S3
3   Y   2023-05-26  2023-06-27  L2          S12
4   Y   2023-05-27  9999-01-01  L2          S12
5   Y   2023-05-28  NaN         L2          S12
```

I extended your example df a bit to test the grouping:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['X', 'L1', 'S1', '2023-06-26', '2023-06-27'], 
        ['X', 'L2', 'S2', '2023-06-27', '9999-01-01'], 
        ['X', 'L2', 'S3', '2023-06-28', np.nan],
        ['Y', 'L1', 'S10', '2023-05-26', '2023-06-27'], 
        ['Y', 'L2', 'S11', '2023-05-27', '9999-01-01'], 
        ['Y', 'L2', 'S12', '2023-05-28', np.nan]
    ],
    columns=['id', 'location', 'serial', 'valid_from', 'valid_to']
)
```

UPD: adjusted the code to handle multiple columns to be replaced with the last value.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @maria, how would I extend this for multiple columns like 'serial'?

Comment: @user3235169 I have adjusted the code to deal with a list of columns.